# Adding item back into an iterable (yield/generator)

Tags: python, generator, yield

I thought this is a great moment to use `yield`, but I'm stuck.

When something fails, I would like to send the item back into the generator. I've read that this is possible, so I'd really like to use my first generator.

```
states = ["IL", "NY", "NJ"]
for state in states:
    ok = do something
    if not ok:
        *add state back as the first-to-deal with in the generator*
```

How to use a generator in such a case?

Comment: This looks like an infinite loop to me. You can just put it into a second list to "deal with it later" otherwise you'll keep processing the same item and putting it back into the list?

Comment: It has an external dependency (based on internet), so when there is connection it will continue, I will add some timer to it and then it is allowed to run infinitely (thought it won't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably referring to a [coroutine](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), which leverages the *yield expression*.  It works a little like this:

```
def co_gen(li):
    for x in li:
        bad = yield x
        if bad is not None:
            print('ack! {}'.format(bad))
            #other error handling
```

and (contrived) usage:

```
states = ["IL", "NY", "NJ"]

gen = co_gen(states)

for x in gen:
    print('processing state: {}'.format(x))
    if x == 'NY':
        y = gen.send('Boo, Yankees!')
        print( 'processing state after error: {}'.format(y))

# processing state: IL
# processing state: NY
# ack! Boo, Yankees!
# processing state after error: NJ
```

Salient points - normal `yield` behavior assigns `None` to `bad`.  If it's not None, something has been `send`-ed into the generator.

When we `send` something into the generator, it *resumes operation until it reaches the next yield expression*.  So keep that in mind - the above control flow in the coroutine isn't what I'd call "standard" since there is no `yield`ing done in the error block.

Here is a coroutine that operates a little more like what you were talking about:

```
def co_gen(li):
    for x in li:
        bad = yield x
        while bad is not None:
            print('error in generator: {}'.format(bad))
            yield
            bad = yield bad

gen = co_gen(states)

for x in gen:
    print('processing state: {}'.format(x))
    if random.choice([0,1]):
        gen.send(x) #discard first yield
        print( 'error: trying {} again'.format(x) )

# processing state: IL
# error in generator: IL
# error: trying IL again
# processing state: IL
# processing state: NY
# error in generator: NY
# error: trying NY again
# processing state: NY
# processing state: NJ
```

We `send` our state back into the generator, and it keeps yielding it until we stop sending it.

Comment: Does not address the 'add state back as the first-to-deal with in the generator' requirement, since 'NJ' is returned after the first 'NY' (which resulted in error).

Comment: @isedev yes, you can put `yield`s in to the `#error handling` block, like I said.  I'll make it more explicit.

Comment: It really does what I hoped for, but it really seems a lot more complicated than I thought it would be...

Comment: Focusing on the latter part of the code, what exactly do the 3 yields do (it really seems so overly complicated)

Comment: Also, why is directly `for x in co_gen(states):` not possible?

Comment: @PascalvKooten addressing the last, you need a reference to your generator to `send` things into it, so you need to bind it to a variable first.

Comment: As for why the three `yield`s, the top one is the "normal" yield.  The two in the `while` loop are the "error loop." You don't want anything back immediately when you first `send`, so there's a blank `yield` there.  The bottom `bad = yield bad` then happens back up at the top of your `for x in gen` loop.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to do what you're asking with regular generators and `gen.send()` and `sent_back = yield x`, your code will be very complicated. It may be easier to write your own [iterator type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), which supports a method other than `send` for getting the "sent back" items:

```
class SendBackIter(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.sent_back = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.sent_back:              # if the stack is not empty...
            return self.sent_back.pop() # return the last item from the sent_back stack
        return next(self.iterator)      # otherwise return an item from our iterator

    def send_back(self, obj):
        self.sent_back.append(obj)
```

If you only need to deal with repeating an item that just came out of the iteration, you could make it simpler yet:

```
def RepeatableIter(object);
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.last_item = None
        self.repeat = False   # client code can set this to True to repeat the last value

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.repeat:
            self.repeat = False # only repeat once, by default
        else:
            self.last_item = next(self.iterator)

        return self.last_item
```

Here's how you could use that last version:

```
it = RepeatableIter(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
for item in it:
    if is_not_ok(item):
        it.repeat = True # this means we will get the same item on the next iteration
    else:
        do_something(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ok(i):
    from random import randint
    return bool(randint(0,1))


def mygen(iterable):
    def helper(iterable):
        for i in iterable:
            elem = yield i
            if elem:
                iterable.append(elem)

    it = helper(iterable)
    sendBack = False
    while True:
        try:
            if sendBack:
                print "Sending back {0}".format(i)
                i = it.send(i)
            else:
                i = it.send(None)
            if ok(i):
                sendBack = False
                yield i
            else:
                sendBack = True

        except StopIteration:
            break

x = range(10)

print list(mygen(x))
#Sending back 1
#Sending back 5
#Sending back 7
#Sending back 1
#Sending back 7
#[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 1, 7]
```

Two generators, sending back the value if the return value evaluates to false for some function. (random in this case).

Comment: It should be put to the front though, not to the end?

Answer (score 0):

You may prepend them back with `chain`, for example.

```
states = iter(["IL", "NY", "NJ"])
processed = []
for state in states:
    ok = do_something(*args, processed, **kwargs)
if not ok:
    restored_states = itertools.chain(iter(processed), states)
```